# How to actually scroll with popup-tip :scroll-bar t?

Tags: scrolling, popup

Following this [blog post](http://blog.jenkster.com/2013/12/popup-help-in-emacs-lisp.html), I am interested in using `popup.el` for my own purposes. In the post, he mentions to add a scroll bar with the `:scroll-bar` argument. If I include the `:scroll-bar t` option in `popup-tip` a scroll bar is displayed, but I couldn't find any way to actually use it. Is this functionality just not implemented? If it is, could you provide an example?

```
(defun hlwm/object-tree ()
  "Show the current hlwm object tree in a buffer."
  (let* ((shell-command-switch "-c")
     (object-tree-string
      (shell-command-to-string "herbstclient object_tree")))
    (popup-tip object-tree-string
           :point (point)
           :around t
           :height 30
           :scroll-bar t
           :margin t)))
```

Comment: Dunno whether it is pertinent here, but Emacs scroll bars generally depend on the toolkit or platform.